# Why doesn't PulseView/sigrok-cli have any available hardware drivers on Ubuntu 23.04?

Tags: 23.04

I am on Ubuntu 23.04 attempting to use PulseView/sigrok-cli with a `fx2lafw` driver. However, my logic analyzer, a Noname Saleae Logic clone, is not detected. In fact, it seems like neither sigrok-cli nor PulseView have any available hardware drivers. The dropdown in PulseView when adding a device is empty:

[image: Connect to Device dialog]

And in "About", there are no drivers listed under "Supported hardware drivers":

[image: About dialog]

I have `sigrok-firmware-fx2lafw` installed, so it should at least have that.

I tried using the AppImage but it also fails to run on Ubuntu 23.04:

```
pulseview: /tmp/.mount_PulseVX19KrX/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0)
pulseview: /tmp/.mount_PulseVX19KrX/usr/lib/libselinux.so.1: no version information available (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmount.so.1)
pulseview: symbol lookup error: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_module_open_full
```

Answer (score 2):

This is due to a bug specific to Ubuntu 23.04, not a bug in PulseView or sigrok. Further discussion:

- [Ubuntu Launchpad Bug #2025248](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsigrok/+bug/2025248)
- [libsigrok bug #1433](https://sigrok.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1433)

For now, you can work around this bug by installing Debian's sigrok packages, which do not contain this bug:

- [libsigrok4](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsigrok4)
- [libsigrokcxx4](https://packages.debian.org/sid/libsigrokcxx4)
- [pulseview](https://packages.debian.org/sid/pulseview)

You can do this in a quick-and-dirty way by downloading the packages and using `dpkg`. For example, on an `amd64` machine:

```
# these versions may be out of date - check Debian's website for the latest
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/pulseview/pulseview_0.4.2-3+b1_amd64.deb \
  http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libsigrok/libsigrok4_0.5.2-4_amd64.deb \
  http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libs/libsigrok/libsigrokcxx4_0.5.2-4_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i pulseview_0.4.2-3+b1_amd64.deb libsigrok4_0.5.2-4_amd64.deb libsigrokcxx4_0.5.2-4_amd64.deb
```

Comment: ... and 23.10, as it seems. Thanks for the answer.